# How to remove outgoing edges from all vertices not equal to "x"

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed graph 'g' with 115 nodes and 1098 edges. It is a hyperlink graph (i.e. nodes are websites and edges represent existence of a hyperlink).

I want to remove all the outbound edges from all vertices that are not from a particular node of interest (id=7). I am trying to create a graph representing only the outlinks from a particular website (i.e. which websites it links to).

I have tried various attempts at using the `delete.edges` function, but I am very confused about how to achieve this.

I have also tried:

```
g[1:6,] <- FALSE
```

followed by:

```
g[8:1098,] <- FALSE
```

But this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your code does not work, it would be great to have a reproducible example, with data. I suspect that your graph has vertex names and you are mixing up the vertex names and the numeric vertex ids. Anyway, the simplest way is probably:

```
library(igraph)
links <- cbind(from=c( 2, 3, 7, 7, 7),
                 to=c(10,11,12,13,14))
g <- graph.edgelist(links)

str(g)
# IGRAPH D--- 14 5 -- 
# + edges:
# [1] 2->10 3->11 7->12 7->13 7->14

g[-7,] <- FALSE

str(g)
# IGRAPH D--- 14 3 -- 
# + edges:
# [1] 7->12 7->13 7->14
```